# Array loses values after loop in Vbscript

Tags: arrays, loops, vbscript

This is the code:

```
'creates the msxml object
Set xmlDoc = CreateObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument.6.0")
Dim retVal

'load the xml data of the script
retVal=xmlDoc.load(argFilePath)

Dim fso, folder, sFolder
Dim xmlDataPath, curNode

'get input folder
Set curNode=xmlDoc.selectSingleNode("//ScriptXmlData/inputFilePath")
Dim inputFolder, outputFolder, hotLoc
inputFolder=CSTR(curNode.text)

'location of jdf files
sFolder=inputFolder

'creating file getting object
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set folder = fso.GetFolder(sFolder)

Dim amount, fName, arrC, i
i=0

'loop for getting amounts
For each folderIdx In folder.files
    If fso.GetExtensionName(folderIdx.Name) = "jdf" Then

        'increase array size
        Redim arrC(i)

        'get folder name
        fName=folderIdx.Name

        'get file path
        xmlDataPath = sFolder+"\"+fName

        'load the xml data of the script
        retVal = jdfDoc.load(xmlDataPath)

        'get amount
        Set curNode = jdfDoc.selectSingleNode("//jdf:JDF/jdf:ResourceLinkPool/jdf:ComponentLink")
        amount = curNode.getAttribute("Amount")

        'Create array that holds amount
        arrC(i)=amount
        i=i+1

    End If
Next

wscript.echo arrC(0)
wscript.echo arrC(1)
wscript.echo arrC(2)
```

Our problem is that once arrC exits the loop, some of its values go missing.
For example, inside the loop our array is:

```
arrC(0)=100
arrC(1)=150
arrC(2)=200
```

Once it leaves the loop, as in the test in the end of the code, its values are :

```
arrC(0)=""
arrC(1)=""
arrC(2)=200
```

Can someone please explain?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ReDim` doesn't preserve the elements of an array when used without the keyword `Preserve`. Change the line

```
Redim arrC(i)
```

into

```
Redim Preserve arrC(i)
```

You don't need an index variable, BTW. When you initialize the `arrC` as an empty array outside the loop, you can use the upper bound as your index:

```
ReDim arrC(-1)

For Each folderIdx In folder.files
  If fso.GetExtensionName(folderIdx.Name) = "jdf" Then
    ...
    ReDim Preserve arrC(UBound(arrC)+1)
    arrC(UBound(arrC)) = amount
  End If
Next
```

However, since `ReDim Preserve` actually creates a *new* array and copies the existing elements from the old one, it's bound to perform poorly with increasing array size. You may want to use an [array list](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.arraylist.aspx) instead:

```
Set arrC = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")

For Each folderIdx In folder.files
  If fso.GetExtensionName(folderIdx.Name) = "jdf" Then
    ...
    arrC.Add amount
  End If
Next
```

Comment: Very thorough!! Thank you very much you are great! Can you think of a way this would happen with a variable? Happened to us before but we were able to avoid it...

Comment: What kind of variable and in which context?

Comment: We created our own "Replace" function, which was in a loop. We put the result string in a variable. The loop ran 3 times, each replacing something else, then outside the loop the variable would lose its value

Comment: Might have been an issue with the scope of the variable. Hard to say without seeing the actual code.